# What locationManager.requestLocationUpdates do?

Tags: android, locationmanager

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 2500, 2,  this);

You need to walk 2 meters in every 2.5seconds to request for new location?. Correct me if i am wrong. Thank you.

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. minTime – Wise choice of value for minTime will help you reduce
   power consumption. What you need to keep in mind is that elapsed
   time between location updates will never be less than minTime, but
   it can be greater, because it is influenced by the implementation of
   each given Provider and the update interval requested by other
   running applications.
2. minDistance – Unlike minTime this parameter can be turned off by
   setting it’s value to 0. However, if minDistance is set to a value
   greater than 0, location provider will only send updates to your
   application if location has changed at least by given distance. This
   parameter is not a great power saver like minTime, but it should be
   kept in mind although.

These two parameters work in AND relation, so in order to receive location update, both of their conditions need to be achieved (i.e. more then 5 seconds has passed, and the distance change is greater than 10 meters).

You can check this link:
https://blog.codecentric.de/en/2014/05/android-gps-positioning-location-strategies/

Comment: what if my minTime is 5 seconds and my elapse time is 3 seconds? it is good?

Comment: If your elapse time is less than the minTime nothing will happen. As mentionned the conditions needs to be achieved in order to get the location update